# How to run 3 queries and return output via model to view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net, npgsql, .net-6.0

My controller (this is code to filter transaction performed between dates and calculate sum (income and expense)):

```
public IActionResult AllTransactionsList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
        var dataset = new DataSet();

        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        connection.Open();

        Console.WriteLine(startDate);

        /*query to account name, type, date, amount note from transactions and account table based on transaction_id*/
        var query = String.Format(@"SELECT a.account_name, a.type, DATE(t.date), t.transaction_id, t.amount, t.note 
                                    FROM transaction AS t
                                    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id
                                    WHERE t.date BETWEEN '{0}' 
                                      AND '{1}' ORDER BY t.date;", startDate, endDate);

        /* query to calculate sum of all rows in amount column from transaction table* of type="income"*/
        var incomeQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS income, a.type 
                                          FROM transaction AS t
                                          INNER JOIN account AS a
                                                ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
                                          WHERE a.type='income'
                                            AND t.date BETWEEN '{0}' and '{1}' 
                                          GROUP BY a.type", startDate, endDate);

        /* query to calculate sum of all rows in amount column from transaction table type="expense"*/
        var expenseQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS expense, a.type
                                           FROM transaction AS t
                                           INNER JOIN account AS a
                                                 ON t.account_id = a.account_id
                                           WHERE a.type='expense'
                                             AND t.date BETWEEN '{0}' and '{1}'
                                           GROUP BY a.type", startDate, endDate);

        using var sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        List<Transaction> allTransactionLists = new List<Transaction>();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                allTransactionLists.Add(new Transaction
                {
                    TransactionId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["transaction_id"]),
                    AccountName = Convert.ToString(reader["account_name"]),
                    Type = Convert.ToString(reader["type"]),
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]),
                    Amount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["amount"]),
                });
            }
        }

        var model = new AllTransactionViewModel();
        model.AllTransactions = allTransactionLists;
        ViewBag.Message = "dataset";

        return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.AllTransactions)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@item.AccountName</td>
            <td>@item.Amount</td>
            <td>@item.Date</td>
            <td>@item.Type</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='/HOME/TransactionInfo?id=@item.TransactionId'">View details</button></td>
        </tr>
}
```

AllTransactionsViewModel:

```
public class AllTransactionViewModel
{
    public List<Transaction> AllTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that, 3 queries(1: to filter transactions between dates,2: to calculate income, 3:to calculate expense ), I was able to filter the list and return the model, but I was not able to get income and expense query data and return that.

Comment: you will find that you never run incomeQuery or expenseQuery, you should create a data later which holds the plumbing....(`sing var sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        List<Transaction> allTransactionLists = new List<Transaction>();`,) for each query then at the 
View lever you have cleaner code... you can then put the results into ur view model

Comment: you should really look at using EF Core 6, there is a provider https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/